# A problem using theErdős–Szekeres theorem

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

Suppose n is a positive integer and suppose $ N>n^3$ an integer. I have to prove that every sequence of N real numbers contains a strictly rising sub sequence in the length of n+1, or a strictly decreasing sub sequence in the length of n+1 or a sub sequence in the length of n+1 that each on of its terms has the same value.
The answer uses the Erdős–Szekeres theorem. I started with showing that there is a rising sub sequence with the length of $n^2 +1$ or a decreasing sub sequence with the length of $n +1$ .Then I tried to do something with the distances between every couple of terms in the sub sequence to prove that they different from each other (by using the Erdős–Szekeres theorem again).

Comment: Why don't you start by showing that there is either a subsequence of length $n+1$ is which all terms have the same value, or else a subsequence of length $n^2+1$ in which no two terms have the same value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume there is no subsequence of length n+1 that all terms has same value (Otherwise, it's done). Then starting from $a_1$, for all $a_i$ remove all the remaining terms equal to $a_i$ (Which means at most $n-1$ terms for each i). So we get a subsequence which has length $\gt \dfrac{n^3}{n}=n^2 $ such that all elements of this subsequence are different. Now apply Erdős–Szekeres theorem, because all terms are different this finishes the proof.